# Prometheus is giving "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, prometheus, performance-testing, outofrangeexception, prometheus-python-client

I am trying get metric in list form using [prometheus_api_client](https://pypi.org/project/prometheus-api-client/)
It worked effectively a few days back but now it is throwing error for the same code.

The error occur in the following line

```py
my_metric_object = metric_object_list[1] # one of the metrics from the list
print(my_metric_object)
```

Basic queries are giving me results. I am trying to use range queries(list of metric that happened in a timeframe) to finally convert and use them in DataFrames.

Comment: Have to try to print `metric_object_list` and see what's inside it?

Comment: It looks like `metric_object_list` has less then two objects. Try adding `print(len(metric_object_list))` before cited code block.

Comment: @dinhit I tried printing it the same error comes up.

Comment: i was using a vm to do this so the linux time was all messed up. Looks like the code was all fine and good. Thanks @dinhit